# jquery multiselect from two selects into one?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I'm trying to figure out how to create a multiselect form that has two selects that allow you to move criteria into a third select.  I did take a look at:

http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

and

//http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-multiselect-plugin-with-themeroller-support/ 
(I'm new, so I can only post one link... :-) )

but they both look like they only allow a one-to-one selection, rather than the two-to-one that I'd like to implement...

Something like this:

```
<!-- user selects multiple values from this and the selected options are moved to third select onclick -->
<select id="select1" name="select1[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>

<!-- user also selects multiple values from this and the selected options are moved to third select onclick -->
<select id="select2" name="select2[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>
</select>

<!-- this is the target for the previously selected options -->
<select id="target" name="target[]" disabled>
<!-- all of the selected options from select1 and select2 are placed here onclick -->
</select>
```

Is this possible?  Does anyone have a working example, or a link that illustrates this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a button with an id of 'add"

make selections hit the add button

with this code attached to the button

```
$('#add').click(function() {  
 return !$('#select1 option:selected,#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#target');  
});
```

Comment: Does that actually return false to stop the default click action while running the code, because that is awesome. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: This works.  Also, you don't need the remove because appendTo by default will move the element from the beginning select and into the target select.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to tailor this to your needs:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select1, #select2").change(function() {
        $("#target").append($(":selected", $(this)).remove());
    });
});
```

It finds the selected item from the dropdown, removes it, and appends it to the target dropdown.